# Is every finite distributive lattice a finite Heyting algebra?

Tags: lattice-orders, heyting-algebra

It is known that every Heyting algebra is a distributive lattice. I was wondering if the reverse is true in the finite case. That is, every finite distributive lattice is a (finite) Heyting algebra.

I think that the answer is yes by the next reasoning, but I am not completely convinced. Take a distributive lattice $L$, then one can use Birkhoff's representation theorem to get that the ideal lattice of the poset of join-irreducible elements is isomorphic to $L$, i.e. $L \cong \mathcal{I}(\mathcal{J}(L)).$ So we can use the poset $\mathcal{J}(L)$ to construct the topology of its open sets with base $U_x=\{ y \in \mathcal{J}(L) \ \vert \ y \preceq x \}.$ Since the open sets of a topological space form a Heyting algebra, we are done. Am I missing something? Maybe there is a simpler proof...

Thank you for your time in advance!

Comment: A lattice is Heyting if there is, for every pair $a,b$ an element $x$ that is maximal with the property $$a\wedge x\leqslant b$$in a finite Heyting algebra, there are only a finite number of elements satisfying the last property and $x$ is just the sup of all of them

Comment: I do not see why there is just one maximal $x$ satisfying $a \wedge x =b.$ In my case $L$ is distributive but not necessarily complete.

Comment: A finite lattice is always complete. The sup of $S=\{s_1,\cdots,s_n\}$ is $$s_1\vee\cdots\vee s_n$$Also, it's not $a\wedge x=b$, but $a\wedge x\leqslant b$

Comment: You are completely right! I forgot that every finite lattice is complete. Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An [Heyting algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heyting_algebra) is a bounded lattice $L$ such that, for every pair $a,b\in L$ there  is an element $(a\Rightarrow b)\in L$ such that $$a\wedge x\leqslant b\leftrightarrow x\leqslant(a\Rightarrow b)$$In particular, you can see that $a\Rightarrow b$ is the sup of the set $$A=\{x\in L|a\wedge x\leqslant b\}$$
In the case of a finite lattice, $A=\{x_1,\cdots,x_n\}$, so there is a sup $$s=x_1\vee\cdots\vee x_n$$ to prove that $a\wedge s\leqslant b$ just use that $L$ is a distributive lattice, so $$a\wedge\bigvee_ix_i=\bigvee_ia\wedge x_i\leqslant b$$

Comment: Rephrasing this: note that every bounded lattice satisfying the arbitrary distributive property $a \land \bigvee\limits_i x_i = \bigvee\limits_i a \land x_i$ is a Heyting algebra. If the bounded lattice is finite, then the arbitrary distributive property follows from the finitary distributive property.